# Firebase Phone Authentication on device with no SIM card

Tags: android, firebase, react-native, firebase-authentication

I am trying to do phone authentication on a device that has **no** SIM Card, with the phone number inputted is active in **another** device. The result I get from this test in Android is that I get **unknown** error ( the error message is "unknown" ).

More interestingly, the result **vary** from device to device. I tested 4 devices, 2 of them successfully "requested" code using phone number in another device and the SMS is sent successfully ( and the code in the SMS works ), while another 2 showing the error above.

The devices that are successful:

- Xiaomi A1 - Android Oreo
- Samsung Galaxy Note 2 - Android Kitkat

The devices that show the error:

- Xiaomi Redmi 5s - Android Oreo
- Oneplus 3 - Android Oreo

**Expected result:**

All devices should be able to request the code through SMS, although it doesn't have SIM card.

Comment: I am having same issue. :-(

Comment: I assume that when the user types his number (from another device that has on it this number ) in the NO SIM card device you call a web service that is responsible for sending the SMS. Right? If yes, I can not understand what has to do the device with anything that is going wrong concerning the request of the code.

Comment: @paokg4 so after the user submits his/her phone number, I directly try to sign the user in using that phone number with Firebase. Interestingly, exactly same code produces vary result on different devices, as stated above. I wonder if somebody has experienced this and found the solution

Comment: @Rumit did you find a workaround or solution for this?

Comment: @William not yet.. :-( please post your answer if you find it. so will i.

Comment: @William Did you try to use `TelephonyManager.SIM_STATE_ABSENT` to check whether the device has a SIM card on it and then use a different behavior for your app in case the device does not have a SIM?

Comment: @paokg4 Thanks for the suggesstion. Actually we have done that, so what we did was to send the SMS using other SMS provider, but unfortunately it is a paid service ( pay per sent SMS ). We are trying to cut our budget, that's why we are trying to use Firebase ( which has 10K free auth SMS / month )

Comment: @Rumit I just tried to do the phone auth again today, and all devices work well ( they send SMS ) now. I don't know what has happenned as there is nothing changed in my project code.

Comment: @William , no luck, if i found solution, i will give answer.